# Why res.cookie is working from postman and doesn't from browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, axios

I trying to set a token from my nodejs server after login.
My client side is react app and i make the post request with axios.

When i try to login from postman i see the token in my cookie but in the browser there is no cookie.

This is the server:

```
res.cookie("token", token, { httpOnly: true }).sendStatus(200);
```

This is the client:

```
  return axios.post(serviceUrl + "auth/login", data).then(response => {
    return response.data;
  });
```

Comment: You are trying to set the cookie on the client with the token you've generated from the server right?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: Have you checked out sites like this one? https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session  There are lots of front end cookie management tools depending on the framework you are using.  All you are doing in the client side code is returning the data, not storing it (specifically the cookie) anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think reason could be not passing domain option when you are trying to set a cookie. Please try passing  `domain : "\"` option like

```
res.cookie("token", token, { httpOnly: true, domain : '\' }).sendStatus(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Chrome doesn't set cookies in localhost. 
I checked in edge and it worked as expeted.

Answer (score 0):

By default, cookies are not stored for the localhost (Chrome). If you want to walkaround this, you can simply add key in chrome dev tools. Go to Application>Storage>Cookies and paste "token" inside.